# iTextSharp dll HTML string creating nested tag exception

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am in middle of developing the application of a MCQ exam website. I am facing a strange issue in iTextSharp.

My questions in the database (under the HTML), have some HTML snippets in the question string. Suppose there is a question with a sample HTML in the string and I have asked the students to find out the syntax error in it.

Post exam I generate the PDF containing the reports where I make a table containing the question and the response from the student. As I make the HTML using the itextsharp dll, I get the error for nested tag while generating the report **since the question text already has a wrong snippet in it**.

I want to make the XMLWorkerHelper to ignore those kind of situations where these kind of situation arises. Also I understand that my question text is making a wrong HTML. How do I overcome this situation?

Comment: You're using iTextSharp which is an old version of iText (I'm assuming version 5). The current version is iText 7 for .NET, and XML Worker has been replaced by the pdfHTML add-on. Read the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) to find out more about the history of HTML to PDF conversion. The answer to your question is in the FAQ entry [Does my HTML have to be valid XML?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/does-my-html-have-be-valid-xml)

Comment: I am using the version 5.5.11.0.

Comment: That\s a maintenance release for iText 5. The term *maintenance release* means that no new features will be added to this version, only bug fixes to help out paying customers who aren't ready to upgrade yet. Are you a paying customer? In which context are you using iText? **Regarding your question:** fixing broken HTML is done in iText 7 + pdfHTML, but it's not something that will be implemented in iText 5.5.11.0 or any iText 5.x.y.z release. New development is only done for iText 7.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution that repairs the HTML before rendering in iText, you should update your tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I used the HTTPUtility.HtmlEncode(String) to solve the issue.